# What is css "[class*=my-class] .my-subclass" doing?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I inherited some css and I have searched everywhere online to understand what is being expressed by a block of css that looks like:

```
 [class*=wrapper] .logo {
                padding-top: 32px !important;
            }
```

What is the asterisk and square brackets doing?

It is hard to search for [ and * on google... Sorry if the question is dumb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It selects an element with class `logo` that has an ancestor that has `wrapper` somewhere in its class attribute. For example note that the class `burgerwrapper` also leads to the element being selected below.

```css
[class*=wrapper] .logo {
  color: #f99;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">Not selected</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo">
    Selected
  </div>
</div>

<div class="burgerwrapper">
  <div class="logo">
    Selected
  </div>
</div>
```

See http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/ for some background information on attribute selectors.

Answer (score 3):

*what square brackets doing*

> **Attribute selectors**
>
> CSS 2.1 allows authors to specify rules that match elements which have
>   certain attributes defined in the source document.

[Attribute selectors w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors)

*What is the asterisk*

> **Substring matching attribute selectors**
>
> [att*=val] Represents an element with the att attribute whose value
>   contains at least one  instance of the substring "val". If "val" is
>   the empty string then the  selector does not represent anything.

[Substring matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings)

To sum it up in you example:

```css
[class*=wrapper] .logo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>not this</div>
  <div class="logo">this</div>
  <div class="logo">this</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>not this</div>
  <div class="logo">not this</div>
  <div>not this</div>
</div>
```

Select child elements with class `.logo` that their parent element has attribute class with value `wrapper` appears somewhere in that attribute.

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation and references.

Comment: Note that some attribute selectors including `*=` do not appear in CSS2.1; they appear in Selectors 3. It would be wise to link there instead.